# Redirect permanently all possible domains and subdomains to https without www (https://example.com)

Tags: apache, performance, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have a site that is getting a lot of traffic so performance is critical. I'm using apache and ubuntu.

I'm trying to redirect all possible domain possibilities to `https://example.com` including all subdomains (`https://test.example.com`).

Here is what I have currently:

```
RewriteEngine On

# match any URL with www and rewrite it to https without the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# match urls that are non https (without the www)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I feel like the above code is doing extra rerouting/work. Is there a more straight forward solution (for a faster performance) either in the virtual host file or .htaccess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all three conditions

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Explanation: if `not https` *OR* `not example.com` then redirect to `https://example.com/xxx`

To answer your question about performance: rewriting in `.htaccess` may be slower than rewriting in Apache config file.

Comment: thank you for that, but what should I write if I want to put it in my apache config file?

Comment: Also, `subdomain.example.com` redirects to `https://example.com` but it should redirect to `https://subdomain.example.com`

Comment: Here is an example: http://tltech.com/info/rewriterule-in-htaccess-vs-httpd-conf/ . For `subdomain`, I'm a bit surprised since you mention `everything` in your question. Remind me your rules scheme, just to make sure we're on the same wavelength